# How to access S3 bucket name and end point from instance metadata?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I created S3 bucket using Cloud formation template script.

Now i want to access S3 bucket name and end point from instance metadata.

Any help?

Comment: Are you saying that you used a CloudFormation template to create an Amazon S3 bucket AND deploy a new Amazon EC2 instance, and that you wish your application on the EC2 instance to be able to access the bucket but you don't know its name? Please feel free to Edit your question to provide more details, including what you have tried so far and what errors/difficulties you have encountered, so that we can better assist you.

Comment: Exactly, I used a CloudFormation template to create an S3 bucket and to create a EC2 instance.I want my application on the EC2 to be able to access the bucket.How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

To enable applications running on an Amazon EC2 instance to access Amazon S3 (or any AWS service), you can [create an IAM Role for the EC2 instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) and assign it to the instance.

Applications on that instance that use the AWS SDK to make API calls to AWS will automatically have access to credentials with permissions described in the assigned role.

Your particular situation is slightly difficult because the CloudFormation template will create a bucket with a unique name, while your IAM Role will want to know the exact name of the Amazon S3 bucket. This can be accomplished by referring to the S3 bucket that was created within the CloudFormation template.

The template would need to create these resources:

- [AWS::S3::Bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html)
- [AWS::IAM::Role](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html) to define the permissions
- [AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-instanceprofile.html) to link the role to the EC2 instance
- [AWS::EC2::Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html) that refers to the IAM Role

Within the definition of the IAM Role, the ARN for the S3 bucket would need to refer to the bucket created elsewhere in the template. This would require a bit of string manipulation to insert the correct value into the policy.

If you run into difficulty, feel free to create another StackOverflow question showing the template that you have been working on, highlighting the part that is causing difficulty.